# culturally accepted adjectival antonym of 'non sequitur'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

If one were to coin the adjective 'sequitur' as an antonym of 'non sequitur', would this be generally understood in English?  'Sequitur' is currently an accepted English noun meaning 'conclusion.'

If not, what culturally accepted antonyms of 'non sequitur' might exist, varying as little as possible in their etymology or connotations from that term?

Silenus left a comment showing the context in which I intend to use this word:

> "His **non-sequitur** response really confused me."

What would be the opposite of a "non-sequitur response": a "___ response"?

Comment: No, people would assume you didn't know how to use the term "non-sequitur". "It follows (then) that..."

Comment: Do you want an adjective or noun? 'Non sequitur' is a noun in English (despite it being a verb phrase in Latin).

Comment: Please give an example sentence showing how you want to use this adjective. It isn't clear what you want it to mean: an adjective that is the antonym of a noun meaning "not a conclusion"?

Comment: @Walrus - you have asked for *an adjectival antonym* even though your word (non sequitur) is a noun ?

Comment: @Walrus - can you post a sample sentence where the word you want is missing please?

Comment: *Non sequitur* can be used as an adjective, but when it is it is usually hyphenated into a phrasal adjective: *non-sequitur*. People say things like "His non-sequitur response really confused me."

Comment: @Silenus - fair enough (although I'm doubtful this is the usage Walrus had in mind (the OP title notwithstanding)).  *Non sequitur* is way more common as a noun than as an adjective, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @Dan, definitely agree. I thought he wanted an adjective, though, because he speaks about coining one using "sequitur". Walrus, speak up! :)

Comment: How about **implied**?

Comment: hey guys I am looking for an adjective here, thanks.  @Silenus' usage is the intended one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with the archaic adjective ***sequent***, defined [here](https://www.google.com/#q=define%20sequent) as "following in a sequence or as a logical conclusion."

You can't get any closer in etymology or connotation.

Comment: Nice word, I've not heard it before.

Comment: This is a very technical term. __Consequence__ is the more recognizable cognate.

Comment: @Dan, are you referring to its use in some logics when people speak of "sequent calculus"? Outside of that, I don't think it's technical, merely archaic. And in terms of etymology, connotation, and overall *flavor* it fits the poster's desires.

Comment: @Silenus - did you mean the comment immediately above to be to me ? (nice word btw)

Comment: @Dan, whoops. Yeah, I mean't Mitch

Answer (score 2):

Well, since we're looking for an ***adjective***, the obvious choices would be:

> consequent
>
> relevant
>
> coherent
>
> cogent

All found in [the Greatest Online Dictionary Ever](http://dictionary.reference.com/)

Comment: Not coherent or cogent, they are too particular and oblique in meaning to 'it does follow'.

Comment: @Mitch: I'm just covering all bases. It would help if we knew what the fellow is trying to convey.

Answer (score 1):

A ***non sequitur*** is *an inference or a conclusion not logically following from the premisses; a response, remark, etc., that does not logically follow from what has gone before* (OED).

It is a noun.

An idiomatic antonym would be a '***logical*** conclusion'.

So, based on the example above "His non-sequitur response really confused me." -

*"His **logical** response really helped me understand."*

Comment: @sumelic - No it is not.  But the OP asks for *culturally accepted antonyms of 'non sequitur' ... varying as little as possible in their etymology or connotations from that term?*.  Since *non sequitur* itself is a noun I would say I am offering a reasonable option.

Comment: @sumelic - I saw no need to. The meaning of non sequitur did not seem to be in any doubt (to the OP or to me). I am happy to oblige if it makes my answer clearer.

Comment: hey @Dan -- I've heard non-sequitur used functionally as a noun and an adjective.  When used nominally, I'm guessing it's as a predicate adjective.  At any rate, it is the adjectival use is what I'm seeking here -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to Mirriam-Webster, *sequitur* is a word in its own right. Although, I have never seen it used on its own before.

> **Sequitur:** the conclusion of an inference.

Alternatively, how about ***consequence*** or ***consequent statement?***

The term *logical progression* also applies.

Interestingly enough, there is a term for *a thing which follows* from the discipline of medicine, although it's not used in normal, non-technical English. It's a very nice word though, in my opinion, and would make a good addition to the lexicon of spoken English. It's *sequela.*

> **Sequela:**
>
> 1. an aftereffect of a disease, condition, or injury
> 2. a secondary result

Comment: 'Sequela' is a great word but is only for events, not arguments.

Comment: hey @Charon thanks for the answer.  I did note the nominal use of this form, but am looking for a corresponding adjectival use of the same or similar.

Comment: The OP said they were looking for an adjective but then referred to a noun in the question, so I proceeded how I saw fit.

Comment: @Mitch - I realise that, but who's to say it's meaning can't evolve a little?